# .htaccess 500 Error - Internal Redirect Loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What might be causing an infinite redirect loop in my rewrite rules, given that /some/virtual/host is a virtual host pointing to a differently-named physical location?    Normally I would check logs, but this is a staging/production environment largely beyond my control.  For the same reason, using an .htaccess inside the offending directory is not an option.

```
<Location /some/virtual/host>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the `[OR]` flag in your condition, because when the rule rewrites the URI to `/index.php`, it matches `!/assets/` and thus the rule gets applied again. The `[OR]` flag makes it so it won't check that the file also doesn't exist.

```
<Location /some/virtual/host>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</Location>
```

But this *may* not be what you're aiming for. It all depends on what you hoped to achieve with the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/` condition.

---

EDIT:

> Anything that is not an extant file inside of a directory named "assets" should be redirected to index.php

I assume that you want non-existent files in the assets directory? Then::

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^assets/ index.php [L]
```

assuming the htaccess file is in your document root. You don't need the `<Location>` container.

Comment: Explaining my intent may help.  Anything that is not an extant file inside of a directory named "assets" should be redirected to index.php.